# Counting the number of each part used, from a table with combination of parts

Tags: sql, excel

I have a table counting the number of instances a certain part is used. However, the way the data was collected is messy - it counts each unique combination of parts used separately (so A+B is different from B+A).

Here's an example:

```
Part Number   |   Count
A                  1
A+B                2
B                  3
B+A                4
C                  5
A,C                6
D                  7
D+D+D             10
```

Based on this table, I would like to get a tally of the total number of each part used. So for instance, the count for D from the above table would be 37 (one count of D used 7 times + three counts of D used 10 times).

Envisioned output:

```
Part Number   |   Total Count
A                   13
B                   9
C                   11
D                   37
```

Is it possible to do this with a script, either in SQL or in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

This VBA function will find count occurances in the first column and then multiply by the second column (if numeric).

```
Function find_part(part As String, searchRange As Range) As Long:

Dim r As Range

find_part = 0
For Each r In searchRange.Resize(, 1)
    If Len(part) > 0 And IsNumeric(r.Offset(, 1)) Then
        occurances = (Len(r.Value) - Len(Replace(r.Value, part, ""))) / Len(part)
        find_part = find_part + occurances * r.Offset(, 1)
    End If
Next

End Function
```

Here's how to call it from Excel, and what the return values look like;
[image]